# INDEX returns zero instead of blank value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have a large array of values, each of which can be blank or have a valid value. Zeros are valid values and are distinct from blank cells!

In another sheet I have quite complicated formulas that point to the array and pick values based on some row and column indexing using VLOOKUP, INDEX, INDIRECT, OFFSET (or some other expensive operation). If the required value in the array is blank it should return `-` (or `NA` or something like that).

The problem is that when I use this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(array, row, col)),"-",INDEX(array, row, col))
```

everything works but there is double call of INDEX. This is waste. The array is quite large and this function is obviously my bottleneck and the complete evaluation requires the user to wait quite long.

If I try to make it in two steps, e.g.:

```
A1 = INDEX(array, row, col)
```

and

```
B1 = IF(ISBLANK(A1), "-", A1)
```

it does not work at all because blank value is converted to `0` in cell A1.

So is there a way to make it without double calling the INDEX function?

Comment: @pnuts: thanks for pointing out. I've removed the comments.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to make it without double calling the INDEX function?

Yes, make sure that if a `0` is to be returned there is a `0` to be fetched and if `-` to be returned a `-`. In other words address the issue in the source data.

For example, by selecting the source data range, HOME > Editing – Find & Select, Go To Special…, check Blanks, enter `-`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If desired not to display `-`s, then select the source data range and HOME > Cells – Format, Format Cells…, Custom:

```
0;0;0;
```

or adjust (eg decimal precision) to suit.

> do you have any idea why MS decided to convert blank values to zeros implicitly?

No, but to me that question seems off topic here.

Comment: Upvote for fixing the source data. Good data architecture should always come before fancy formulas.

Comment: Just happening by here and disagreeing with this one.  Seems to me it should be perfectly valid to have blanks and zeroes in the source data; the fundamental issue is INDEX mapping both to zero on the way through [assuming it does - I mean the fact that you can test it for blank in the if condition makes this a slightly strange one].  "-" is a display requirement on the particularly target sheet that doesn't belong in the source data itself.